# Android Rotate Animation not rotating completely

Tags: android, xml, animation

I am using rotate animation(xml) to rotate an ImageView.I have set it to rotate to 360 degrees and then rotate back to 0 degrees.It only rotates to 270 degrees and goes back to 0.Can you explain the reason behind this

rotate.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"

    >
    <rotate
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        >
    </rotate>
    <rotate
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromDegrees="360"
        android:toDegrees="0"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        >
    </rotate>
</set>
```

Code:

```
Animation animation1=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.rotate);
        imageView.setAnimation(animation1);
        imageView.startAnimation(animation1);
```

Comment: set `android:fillAfter` to false.

Comment: no..that is not the problem

Comment: animation set is designed to run animations simultaneously, not one by one. Probably you want to use animations list

Comment: xml doesn't show animations list tag

Comment: separate two animation in different file, then call second animation after 1st end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in java

```
imageView.animate().rotation(360).setDuration(1000).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           btnSingup.animate().rotation(0).setDuration(300);
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is flipping the imageview.I want to rotate it.But thanks for your reply

Comment: just a god damd Y!